Cannot load file './dom' from module 'react-router' - React router dom
I have installed latest react router dom and in package.js its showing "react-router-dom": "^7.0.2".and when i check npm -v react-router-dom its showing 10.9.0. And in my code
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Body from "./components/Body";
import About from "./components/About";
import {
  createBrowserRouter as Router,
  RouterProvider
} from "react-router-dom";

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      <Body />
    </div>
  );
};

const appRouter= createBrowserRouter ([
  { path: "/", element: <AppLayout /> },
  { path: "about", element: <About /> },
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<RouterProvider router= {appRouter} />);

I am getting and error like

@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'react-router/dom' from
'./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.mjs'
D:\Namsthe\node_modules\react-router-dom\dist\index.mjs:13:48   12 |
// index.ts

13 | import { HydratedRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router/dom";
|                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   14 | export * from "react-router";   15 | export
{ @parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file './dom' from module
'react-router'



BTW npm -v react-router-dom is showing you the installed npm version, not react-router-dom. Maybe you meant to use npm list react-router-dom to check the installed version?

React-Router 7 really changed things up how they organize their code. The RouterProvider component is not exported from react-router-dom, it comes from a more deeply nested package, the platform-specific, e.g. DOM-specific, react-router/dom. In v7, react-router is the primary entry point.

Uninstall react-router-dom: npm un react-router-dom

Install react-router: npm i react-router@latest

Update the import to be from react-router
import {
  createBrowserRouter as Router,
  RouterProvider
} from "react-router";



For complete details see:

Installation guide
The Upgrading from v6 migration guide
Changelog

